# While-loop termination

Tags: java, while-loop

If I comment out the line `garbage = scan.nextLine();`, the while-loop runs infinitely. Otherwise, it does not. I understand why it will run infinitely if there were only the print command, but I don't completely understand how the inclusion of the `garbage` variable stops it from running infintely. Can someone explain please?

```java
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class TypeSafeReadInteger
 {
     public static void main(String [] args)
     {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         String garbage;

         System.out.print("Enter age as an integer > ");

         while (! scan.hasNextInt())
         {
             garbage = scan.nextLine();
             System.out.print("\nPlease enter an integer > ");
         }

         int age = scan.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Your age is " + age);
     }
 }
```

Comment: If something is true and you don't do anything to change it, will it ever change to false?

Answer (score 4):

`garbage` is just a variable, what 'stops' the while loop is the `nextLine()` It is a method that waits for user input. The while doesn't continue until your user inputs something using a keyboard and saves the input into the `garbage` variable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know two things:

- `hasNextLine()` *does not* advance the Scanner instance.
- `nextLine()` *does* advance the Scanner instance.

By "advance the Scanner instance", I mean "consume" input. Think of input as a stream, and think of a scanner object as something that is consuming that stream.

Things in a normal stream can only be consumed once. You captured your's in a variable called `garbage`, but you could just as easily have called `scan.nextLine()` without storing the result. I strongly advise you to read the [Javadoc on Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to see which methods advance the Scanner instance and which do not.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code:

```
    while (!scan.hasNextInt())
    {
        scan.nextLine(); // the order of the lines inside the loop makes the difference!
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter an integer > ");
        // when you perform nextLine() here - you reach the beginning of the loop 
        // without a token in the scanner - so you end up looping forever
    }
    int age = scan.nextInt();
```

By the way - as you can see from the example above, `garbage` is redundant.

Comment: Wrong answer as far as an infinite loop is concerned.  In this regard `nextLine()` and `next()` behave the same way.

Answer (score 0):

If the user inputs an integer, then everything works.  If they don't, then you get the infinite loop without the `garbage = scan.nextLine();` line due to the way the Scanner class works.

When you do something like `scan.hasNextInt();`, no characters are actually read from the input.  So if a user input something like "cat" in response to your prompt, then the input would be paused just before the first letter of that word. Since you are looping until there is an integer in the input, nothing further is read and you will loop infinitely because "cat" is just sitting in the input buffer.

By adding in the `scan.nextLine()` you will cause the Scanner to discard everything up to when the user hit <enter> and additional input could be processed.